# Python - Recursively find how many y's it takes to make a x

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to find a recursive solution to find how many units make up a whole. Example of dictionary I am working with:

```
x_dict = {

   'recipes': {
                'video_card':{'parts': {'ram':3, 'gpu':1, 'silicon':20}},
                'ram': {'parts': {'silicon':20}}, 
                'gpu': {'parts':{'silicon': 10, 'copper':10}}
   }
}
```

This is what I have tried so far (at least the one that makes most sense to me)

```
def find_x(x, y, total=0):

  for i in x_dict['recipes'][x]['parts']:
    if i != y:
      return find_x(i, y, total)
    else:
      total += x_dict['recipes'][x]['parts'][y]
  return total


print(find_x('video_card', 'silicon'))
```

output: `20`

Seems to go to `'ram'` in `'video_card'` key and since the first key doesn't match `'silicon'`, the else statements goes and grabs `'silicon'` from `'ram'` and returns that amount only.

debugging shows that only the `'ram'` key was checked for `'silicon'` and that amount was returned.

I need to check `'video_card'`, if a key isn't `'silicon'` I want to search the rest of the recipes to find 'ram' for example and then add the total amount of `'silicon'` it took to make `ram` to a total. (Since I have 3 `ram`s that are needed to make video card, I need to multiply the amount by 3 before adding it to my total.

`find_x('video_card', 'silicon')` should return `90` because there are (3 x ram x 20 silicon) + (1 x gpu x 10 silicon) + (20 silicon in 'video_card' parts)

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: According to your structure, a `video_card` consists of 20 `silicon`, and that's it.  Where are you getting these other numbers?

Comment: @TimRoberts from the component parts: 3x ram and 1x gpu. But it doesn't explain why the video_card recipe itself also has silicon:20, which is not counted.

Comment: This would be easier if your recipe dict were consistently formatted.  I don't think it's possible to write a simple recursive function to traverse data that's not organized in a uniform way.

Comment: I fixed that...it should be counted.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the scroll bar.  The structure looked complete without it.

Comment: Thank you everyone, you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to have a `recipes` dict that gives you the recipe for each item in a consistent way.  Having an extra level of indirection in half of your recipes (the `parts` dict) makes it difficult to write one block of code that can handle either type of recipe.  Keep it simple:

```
>>> recipes = {
...     'video_card': {'ram': 3, 'gpu': 1, 'silicon': 20},
...     'ram': {'silicon': 20},
...     'gpu': {'silicon': 10, 'copper': 10},
... }
```

Once your data is formatted uniformly, you just need to sum up the cost for each ingredient in the recipe (which you can find by calling `find_x` recursively on the ingredients). Make sure to handle the base cases where you're finding the cost of a unit in that same unit (e.g. `find_x('silicon', 'silicon') -> 1`), or trying to find the cost of something that turns out to be some other raw material (e.g. `find_x('copper', 'silicon') -> 0`).

```
>>> def find_x(x, y):
...     if x == y:
...         return 1  # it's the same unit, so it costs 1 of itself
...     if x not in recipes:
...         return 0  # x is a unit that we can't build out of y at all
...     return sum(find_x(i, y) * c for i, c in recipes[x].items())
...
>>> find_x('video_card', 'silicon')
90
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but its giving me a TypeError for the return statement. unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'....trying to figure out where that's coming from.

Comment: I had a key error, as my actually dictionary is much larger and I didn't include it! But I got it to work with a little tweaking thanks to you!! I was stuck on this for a while you really made my day!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your dictionary isn't consistently organized. That's a problem. In each recipe, you should either just specify the parts *and* materials directly, or have separate keys for parts and materials. For example:</strike>

With the corrected dictionary,

```
x_dict = {
   'recipes': {
        'video_card':{'parts': {'ram': 3, 'gpu': 1, 'silicon': 20}},
        'ram': {'parts': {'silicon': 20}}, 
        'gpu': {'parts': {'silicon': 10, 'copper': 10}}
   }
}
```

you can look up the materials for the component parts recursively, and multiply that by the number of parts.

```
def find_x(recipe, material):
    if recipe == material: return 1 # Handle the end recursion case

    # Get the dict for this recipe
    recipe_dict = x_dict["recipes"].get(recipe, None)
    
    if not recipe_dict:
        # No recipe found
        return 0

    # Initialize answer
    answer = 0

    # Recurse for every part
    for partname, partcount in recipe_dict["parts"].items():
        # Add count * quantity of material needed for part to answer
        answer += partcount * find_x(partname, material)

    return answer
```

Running `find_x('video_card', 'silicon')` gives the expected answer `90`

Comment: I realized I didn't put the 'parts' key for 'video_card'. The ram, gpu, and silicon are parts needed to make the 'video_card'. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it!

Comment: I updated my answer for your new dictionary @FaisalMalik

Comment: Thank you again for your time, I got it to work but I'm gonna try solution out as well for learning purposes! :)